# Wild Cantor sets in the plane

Tags: general-topology

Numerous sources indicate that Schoenflies theorem implies that these cannot exist. I cannot see the argument for this implication.  How does the result follow?

Comment: Could you add a definition or a reference to a definition of a "wild Cantor set"?

Comment: Suppose we embed the usual Cantor set into the plane by an injection of the real line.  Call this image C'.  Given any Cantor set C in the plane there is an isomorphism of C onto C'.  If C has no such isomorphism which can be extended to an isomorphism of the plane, then C is wild.

Comment: @Kraimie : By "isomorphism" do you mean a homeomorphism? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes. Apologies for the algebraist's language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the [Denjoy-Riesz theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Riesz_theorem) to find a Jordan curve containing your cantor set.

2) Use the Schoenflies theorem to find a homeomorphism taking this to the standard circle, and then pick a homeomorphism taking a sub-arc of that circle that contains the Cantor set to the real line.

3) Either prove by hand or invoke a theorem that given two Cantor sets in the plane, there's a homeomorphism of the line taking one to the other. (Note that the resulting *embeddings* might be different, but the sets will be the same.) Extend this to a homeomorphism of the plane.

4) If you're unsatisfied about the fact that the two embeddings might be different even though their images aren't the same, fix that by hand. Probably not too hard, though I haven't tried.

Comment: Thank you.  I was entirely unaware of Denjoy–Riesz.